# Reload View Controller Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift-3

Olá, tenho um app e inseri a checagem de conexão a internet no viewDidAppear, queria saber como faço para dar um reload nessa tela quando o usuário clicar em RETRY do Alert, para fazer a checagem novamente.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true
    {
        print("Connected")
    }
    else
    {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Detected", message: "This app requires an Internet connection", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create the actions
        let retry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Retry Pressed")
        }

        controller.addAction(retry)

        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria uma função que que chame essa verificação de conexão. Coloque um @IBAction de um button para chamar essa função de preferencia:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    verificaConexao()
}

func verificaConexao() {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Connected")
    } else {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Detected", message: "This app requires an Internet connection", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create the actions
        let retry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Retry Pressed")
        }

        controller.addAction(retry)

        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction fun reloadButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    verificaConexao
}
```